# How to deal with so-called "fluent" or "builder" interfaces

Tags: scala

They are nice when you know the configuration at compile time, but look rather weird when you need to build an object based on some run-time conditions.

```
val req = Request()

val secureReq = if (needSecurity) req.withSecurity else req
val throttledReq = if (needThrottling) secureReq.withThrottling else secureReq
val pooledReq = if (needPooling) throttledReq.withPooling else throttledReq

// etc etc ad infinitum
```

Maybe there's a better, more succinct way to write this kind of code in Scala?

Comment: It seems like a better interface would take a flag as a parameter, so you could just do `req.withSecurity(needSecurity).withThrottling(needThrottling).withPooling(needPooling)`.

Comment: I'm mostly concerned about external libraries

Comment: Yeah, it's a shame that you can't change a bad third party design.

Comment: You can add the only-if-flag-set method via implicits. Might not be worth it, thougjh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scala implicits to the rescue.

```
    object PimpedBuilders {
        implicit class Pimped[T](val builder: T) extends AnyVal {
          def unless(what: Boolean)(then: T => T): T = 
             if(what) builder else then(builder)
       }
   }

  import PimpedBuilders._
  req
     .unless(!needSecurity){ _.withSecurity}  
     .unless(!needThrottling} { _.withThrottling }
    .unless(!needPooling) { _.wothPooling }
```

etc.

Comment: +1,                                                                                                            but why did you introduce the (double) negation?

Comment: @Bergi, that's just my luck of phantasy :) I can't call call the method `if`, and could not think of an alternative that would sound nice and concise at the moment. `doIf` just sounded clumsy .. :/

Comment: :/ ... I think, it's even worse than `doIf` :) I could go for `ifTrue` I guess ..

Comment: @synapse, indeed. `when` sounds great. Wish, I have thought of it earlier.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is a bit convoluted, but should avoid repeating oneself.

Note that I couldn't check the code on a REPL, but it should give you the idea.

```
/************************************************
 * This part is used once
 ************************************************/
//We define a request-transforming type
type Configuration = Request => Request

/* now we prepare configuration selectively based on a flag
 * the function is curried to store different configurations
 * once, leaving the flag to be defined only as we actually
 * prepare the request.
 * Note that a false flag will give back the identity function
 * from Predef that leaves the argument untouched
 */
def configuring(conf: Configuration)(flag: boolean) = 
  if (flag) conf else identity

//The available configuration types, wrapping the "fluent" calls
val secured_?: Boolean => Configuration = configuring(_.withSecurity)
val throttled_? = configuring(_.withThrottling)
val pooled_? = configuring(_.withPooling)

/************************************************
 * This part is used each time we need 
 * to configure a request
 ************************************************/
val req = Request()

/* prepare a sequence of configurations
 * and compose them sequentially
 */
def configurations: Configuration = Seq(
  secured_?(needSecurity),
  throttled_?(needThrottling),
  pooled_?(needPooling)
).reduce(_.compose(_))

/* apply the combined configuring 
 * function to the new request
 */
val configured = configurations(req)
```